# How to correct html code for apostrophe appearing in Views contextual filter select list?

Tags: views, 8

I am finding that taxonomy terms containing an apostrophe are not rendered correctly when seen in a Views contextual filter select list.

I am working on as school website and Parent's Evening is displayed as `Parent&#039;s evening`

How to correct this?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, are you able to replicate on a fresh install?

Comment: I just checked this on a reasonably fresh 8.8 installation, and don't see this problem. Are you sure it's right in the taxonomy list? Have you linked the select list through a view, or directly?

Comment: You are both correct. This is a bug in my setup somewhere. Thank you for the pointers.